# [Nodejs][AWS-SDK] Read a html file from aws s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, backslash

I use the aws-sdk to get an object on s3. the code is:

```
const params = {
    Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name,
    Key: event.Records[0].s3.object.key,
   };
  const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
  const html = data.Body.toString();
```

But the result of html is:

```
 consolo.log(html) 
 ->
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!-- saved from url=(0042)https:/
/www.linkedin.com/in/jeromedevosse/ -->\n<html lang=\"en\" class=\"gr__linkedin_com\">
```

We can see there are many Newline "\n" and backslash "\" in html.

For now, I use regex to replace them,

```
const html = data.Body.toString().replace(/\\|\\n/g,'');
```

But is there any better solution to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I stumble with the same issue but it was due that before checking the results I was using JSON.stringify. You could check something like that, maybe you could try to use JSON.parse(html);